# Replayed transaction on Gnosis safe 1.1.1 to enable Polygon network. Not working

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

We have a Gnosis safe on 1.1.1 (factory; 0x76E2cFc1F5Fa8F6a5b3fC4c8F4788F0116861F9B) which currently does not support polygon. We wanted to add polygon to our save by replaying the transaction + hex data on the polygon chain to enable polygon access with our old safe.

0x76E2cFc1F5Fa8F6a5b3fC4c8F4788F0116861F9B is the 1.1.1 factory we used ( from our safe creation tx ).

After replaying the transaction, the address on polygon now shows a contract + checkmark.

However, going back to Gnosis webapp, when we go to the Polygon network it cannot fetch balances and it says "read only". It seems like something went wrong

Afterwards we thought, maybe we should try to replay the transaction with the 1.3.0 factory address (0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2) but it seems to fail, the transaction success but the address does not get updated.

Any way of overwriting a contract? or making polygon still possible? all help is appreciated. We do not want to lose our polygon funds.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The Safe web interface on Polygon does only support Safe that have been created with the 1.3.0-L2 version (`0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E`).

If you use another version you will have to rely on the CLI tools (e.g. [Safe tasks](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-tasks) or [Safe CLI](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli)) to interact with your Safe.

Alternatively you can directly interact with the Safe contract using Polygonscan or custom scripts (e.g. based on the [Safe core SDK](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk))